# Fighting with MySQL 5.7 to create a valid Group_by (or alternative) result with no luck

Tags: mysql

I have been fighting for the last two days with no luck making a query for a deployment auditing tool I wrote.  In earlier versions of MySQL I have learned that my old query would likely have had a bug using GROUP BY, but I had never noticed.  So now that the rules have changed in MySQL, I am trying to get reliable results and failing badly.

Here is what I am working with for columns:

> | environment | application       | hostname             | userid  | buildNumber | timestamp           | endTime             | state    | arguments | gitBranch | gulpTest | hash  |

Hash is the only oddball column which is a random integer between 1 and 1,000,000.
I have a UNIQUE constraint on hostname and hash, as well.  All of the other columns are timestamp, varchar, or text columns.

I am trying to get a result of a single application name with the latest deployment from the timestamp:

> Application1, MAX(timestamp), other columns that match the single row
>
> Application2, MAX(timestamp), other columns that match the single row

I know I cannot use GROUP BY, since I cannot say ANY_VALUE for the other column returns, as the values would be random matches.  Using distinct does not work for me either, as it does not limit to single application row return when the other columns are in the query..

This is the old query, that likely had bugs I never noticed:

```
SELECT gitBranch, hostname, environment, application, timestamp, endTime, userid, state, gulpTest, hash FROM deploy WHERE hostname= :hostname AND hash IN(
  select hash from (
    select application, hash, timestamp from (
      SELECT application, hash, timestamp FROM(
        SELECT application , hash, timestamp FROM deploy WHERE hostname= :hostname order by application ,timestamp DESC
      ) AS derived
    ) AS derived2 GROUP BY application) 
  as derived3)
```

If anyone has suggestions on how a I can attack this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.  I am not a DBA, and just goof around on MySQL.  I cant seem to wrap my head around how to get this query to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

One of my coworkers finally took pity on me and my flailing.  Here is the answer that worked for me. Still cannot wrap my head around the answer all that well, but it works.. Hopefully it will help someone else out too..

> SELECT d.* FROM deploy d LEFT OUTER JOIN deploy dd ON d.application = dd.application AND d.timestamp < dd.timestamp WHERE dd.hostname IS NULL AND d.hostname IN (:hostname)